# How to use reactfire with react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, mixins

I'm trying to use 'reactfire' mixin with react native for my app.

I installed the npm module.

```
$ npm install reactfire --save
```

I included the module in my 'index.ios.js' file

```
var ReactFireMixin = require('./node_modules/reactfire');
```

I added the mixin to the class

```
mixins: [ReactFireMixin],
```

I say

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    items: [],
  }
},

componentWillMount: function() {
  var ref = new Firebase('https://<MY APP NAME>.firebaseio.com/tasks');
  this.bindAsArray(ref, 'items');
  console.log(ref);
  console.log(this.state.items);
}
```

And I get

[image: debugger output]

I can use the 'firebase' npm module just fine but not the 'reactfire' one, and I'd like to us the mixin in my app instead of the other alternatives.

I'm also curious about how this particular mixin handles offline usage.

PS: flaw in firebase [documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/react/quickstart.html) because just doing 'mixins: [ReactFireMixin],' doesn't do anything and when developing for react native you don't have a html file.

And yes, I'm a react newb, so this might just be an utter waste of your time.

Here's the full code - [github repo](https://github.com/ferologics/Pomodoro/blob/master/todayView.js)

Comment: What exactly is the question? or the error?

Comment: So, there should be objects displayed in "this.state.items" and the console.log statement should print out the objects because of the bindAsArray() call, but instead the array is empty, and the Firebase reference looks like encrypted

Comment: And my table view is empty, doesn't display any rows of data

Comment: Does the firebase ref look different on web? Looks it may just be minified. I wouldn't be surprised if reactfire doesn't work with react native

Comment: It might be that it doesnt work but I thought that it is, or seen that they stated it somewhere, not sure what you mean by "does the firebase look different on web?"

Comment: I just ran a quick test and ReactFire works fine in React Native for me. Since I have no way to know what's wrong with your approach based on the snippets in your question, I'll put my entire index.android.js in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested and don't see any problems when I use ReactFire in an React Native app (for Android at least).

My entire `index.android.js`:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var Firebase = require('firebase');
var ReactFireMixin = require('reactfire');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableHighlight,
} = React;

var CoolProject = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ReactFireMixin],
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      items: []
    };
  },
  componentWillMount: function() {
    this.ref = new Firebase('https://nanochat.firebaseio.com/chat');
    this.bindAsArray(this.ref, 'items');
  },
  _onPressButton: function() {
    this.ref.push({ name: 'puf', message: this.state.text });
  },
  render: function() {
    var createItem = function(item, index) {
      return <Text>{item.name}: {item.message}</Text>
    };
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        {this.state.items.map(createItem)}
        <View style={styles.horizontal}>
          <TextInput onChangeText={(text) => 
              this.setState({ text: text})} value={this.state.text} />
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButton}>
            <Text>Send</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('CoolProject', () => CoolProject);
```

Note that in many cases it is not necessary to use ReactFire. For example, this is the code that I was using instead of `this.bindAsArray(ref, 'items')`:

So if ReactFire is causing you problems, consider getting the same working without ReactFire.

```
this.ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  var items = [];
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    items.push(child.val());
  });
  this.setState({ 'items': items });
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: It turned out to be a problem with the cloneWithRows function and the difference between using bindAsArray and bindAsObject. Sorry for the late response, you were very very helpful ^^